# Showing music from Windows partition in music folder

Tags: music

I have my music stored on my Windows partition, and I can access them from Ubuntu. Is there anyway to represent them virtually in my music folder in home. What I want to do is similar to how the Windows 7 library folders work. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[Mounting the partition as Denis suggests](https://askubuntu.com/a/104314/458) is ideal if the Music folder is on it's own partition. Even if it is not you can mount any folder under another location using the `-o loop` option to `mount`.

The simpler way maybe to just create a link from the folder containing the Music to your home folder.

Right click on the folder containing the Music and choose "Make Link", then copy the link to your home directory and rename it to something like "Windows Music".

Comment: usually, a folder on windows partitions doesn't support symbolic links.

Comment: The symlink will be in your home directory, which will most likely be a file system that supports symlinks (ext2,ext3,ext4, reiserfs etc). It will point to a folder on perhaps a file system that does not support symlinks (ntfs, fat, etc). It can work that way round.

Comment: you are right,symlink is nice and simple solution.  I mean, you can't make it with right click on ntfs folder in Nautilus, but you can add a symlink with usual syntax `ln -s /from /to` in terminal